# If a firm produced 100 pens with a market value of $1 each, but only 50 were sold, what is the value added to the GDP?

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, markets

Is it 100 dollars or 50 dollars? I'm assuming it is $100 because GDP is the total market value of all final products. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. \$50 would be counted towards consumption, and the rest would be counted as investment (inventory).

Comment: So GDP would increase by $100?

Comment: That is correct.